# Kotlin - How to skip entries on exceptions when mapping and filtering

Tags: android, kotlin, filter, iteration, mapping

I wonder how to skip one entry while mapping or filtering?

```
fun getFilteredList(list: List<String>, match: String): List<String>? {

    val flist = list.filter {
         try {
             // Some parsing logic which can throw exceptions
             val res = SomeParser.parse(match)
             it == res
         } catch (e: Exception){
             // I want to skip this entry to include in flist but still continue 
             // for left of the list entries without return. How to do that?
             return null
         }
     }
     return flist
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just return `true`/`false` from the catch block?

Comment: @Slaw it gives compiler error

Comment: What if you remove the `return` keyword (notice you don't need it for the `it == match`)?

Comment: If I remove the return line inside catch, it gives me error @Slaw

Comment: So `.filter { try { it == match } catch (ex: Exception) { false } }` gives a compilation error?

Comment: Though I also notice you'll be calling `SomeParser.parse` _for each element_ in the list. You might want to pull that out of the filter operation.

Comment: @Slaw Your code works fine. I got compiler error when I used `return false`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Slaw thanks for your suggestions on `SomeParser`. I just wanted to show that the code might get an exception here so I need to skip the current entry. In my real code exception happens for different reason. Thanks again.

Comment: Makes sense. Also, note you might want to return `true` instead since you want the element included in the filtered list. And regarding `return false`, I believe you could use `return@filter false` as well (a qualified return)—see [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#returning-a-value-from-a-lambda-expression).

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for support. You can write the solution in the answer section so that I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your use of the `return` keyword. Your code should look like:

```
// return type no longer needs to be nullable
fun getFilteredList(list: List<String>, match: String): List<String> {
    val flist = list.filter {
         try {
             val res = SomeParser.parse(match)
             it == res
         } catch (e: Exception){
             true
         }
     }
     return flist
}
```

Or, based on your example, just (using ["single-expression function" syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions)):

```
fun getFilteredList(list: List<String>, match: String) = list.filter {
    try {
        it == SomeParser.parse(match)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        true
    }
}
```

***Note:** Both of these will call `SomeParser.parse` for each element in the list. However, you mention this is just an example and the real code works differently (i.e. can't be pulled out of the filter operation).*

---

The reason `return` was giving you an error has to do with lambda expressions. From the [Returning a value from a lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#returning-a-value-from-a-lambda-expression) section of the Kotlin reference:

> We can explicitly return a value from the lambda using the [qualified return](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) syntax. Otherwise, the value of the last expression is implicitly returned.
>
> Therefore, the two following snippets are equivalent:
>
> ```
> ints.filter {
>     val shouldFilter = it > 0 
>     shouldFilter
> }
>
> ints.filter {
>     val shouldFilter = it > 0 
>     return@filter shouldFilter
> }
> ```
>
> [...]

And this is in combination with the fact [`filter` is an `inline` function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html). From the [Non-local retuns](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns) section of the Kotlin reference:

> In Kotlin, we can only use a normal, unqualified `return` to exit a named function or an anonymous function. This means that to exit a lambda, we have to use a [label](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels), and a bare `return` is forbidden inside a lambda, because a lambda cannot make the enclosing function return:
>
> ```
> fun foo() {
>     ordinaryFunction {
>         return // ERROR: cannot make `foo` return here
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> But if the function the lambda is passed to is inlined, the return can be inlined as well, so it is allowed:
>
> ```
> fun foo() {
>     inlined {
>         return // OK: the lambda is inlined
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Such returns (located in a lambda, but exiting the enclosing function) are called non-local returns. [...]

This means when you had `return null` it was actually trying to exit the entire `getFilteredList` function. I'm assuming this is why you have your return type as `List<String>?` instead of `List<String>`. And when you tried `return false` you were trying to return a `Boolean` from a function whose return type was `List<String>?`.

Comment: Perfect answer. Nicely elaborated. Thanks again.